# Syntax Error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment when evaluating keys in object using for-in-loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I have an object called sumMe containing several key/value pairs and a variable called total whose initial value is 0. I'm using a for... in loop to iterate through the keys of sumMe and if the value corresponding to a key is a number, I want to add it to total.

```
const sumMe = {
  hello: 'there',
  you: 8,
  are: 7,
  almost: '10',
  done: '!'
};
let total = 0;

for (let keys in sumMe ) {
  if (typeof(sumMe[keys]) = "number") {
    total + sumMe[keys]
  }
}

console.log(sumMe)
```

I get the following error when I try to evaluate it: *Syntax Error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment*

The expected total should equal 15. It currently reads "0" when correcting for the comparison operator changing "=" to "===" above.

Comment: Comparison is done with `===`, `=` is assignment.

Comment: Also, instead of `total + sumMe[keys]` (which does nothing), you may want to do `total += sumMe[keys]`

Comment: Note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so the parentheses are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality check is missing the second '='.
And maybe you'd like to increase total, so change + to +=.

Write

```
for (let keys in sumMe ) {
  if (typeof(sumMe[keys]) == "number") {
    total += sumMe[keys]
  }
}
```

hth